# Alignment issue after using actionRegion

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

I used the below code to re render the pageBlockSection whenever I choose the relevant picklist. I achieved that thing but what i'm facing is alignment issue.

This is the VF Code i'm using it,

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock mode="edit">
        <apex:outputPanel>
            <apex:outputPanel>
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Audit Information" columns="1" collapsible="false" >
                    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!contact.Languages__c}"/>
                        <apex:outputPanel layout="none">
                                <apex:actionRegion>
                                    <apex:pageBlockSection>
                                        <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Choose_Number__c}" label="### ##### ### ######## ######## #### ### #### ## ####? ## ###, ###### ##### ##### ### #### ######### ##########  ### ######## ### #### ##### ### #### ######">
                                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="testRender"/>
                                        </apex:inputField>
                                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                                </apex:actionRegion>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!contact.By_Mistake__c }" />
                        <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Title}"/>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!contact.MobilePhone}"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Email}" />
                        <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Phone}" />
                        <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Title}" />
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                    <apex:outputPanel id="testRender">
                        <apex:pageBlockSection/>
                        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Show PageBlockSection" collapsible="false" rendered="{!contact.Choose_Number__c == 'Four'}" >
                        </apex:pageBlockSection>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

The output for the above code is shown below,

[image: Unaligned field in Vf page]

I want to align the multipicklist just like other fields are. Could anyone please help me how to achieve this one?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, might be it solve your problem :

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock mode="edit">
    <apex:outputPanel >
        <apex:outputPanel >
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Audit Information" columns="1" collapsible="false" >
                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!contact.Languages__c}"/>
                    <apex:outputPanel layout="none">
                            <apex:actionRegion>
                                <apex:pageBlockSection >
                                    <apex:inputField style="margin-left:18%;" value="{!contact.Choose_Number__c}" label="### ##### ### ######## ######## #### ### #### ## ####? ## ###, ###### ##### ##### ### #### ######### ##########  ### ######## ### #### ##### ### #### ######">
                                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="testRender"/>
                                    </apex:inputField>
                                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                            </apex:actionRegion>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.By_Mistake__c}" />
                    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Title}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.MobilePhone}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Email}" />
                    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Phone}" />
                    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Title}" />
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I tried this but doesn't align properly in VF page.

Comment: I guess only Style issue is there because you've used and even said you were not getting the exact alignment you want after using Actionregion..try to change style in inputfield or i will update my answer by tomorrow !! :)

Answer (score 0):

got the solutions for the above question.

Here the code is,

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">

<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock mode="edit">
        <apex:outputPanel >
            <apex:outputPanel >
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Audit Information" columns="1" collapsible="false" >
                    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1"> 
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!contact.Languages__c}"/>

                        <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
                            <apex:outputLabel value="### ##### ### ######## ######## #### ### #### ## ####? ## ###, ###### ##### ##### ### #### ######### ##########  ### ######## ### #### ##### ### #### ######"/>
                            <apex:actionRegion >
                                <apex:inputField id="test" value="{!contact.Choose_Number__c}" >
                                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="testRender" />
                                </apex:inputField>
                            </apex:actionRegion>
                        </apex:pageblockSectionItem>   
                        <apex:inputField value="{!contact.By_Mistake__c }" />
                        <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Title}"/>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!contact.MobilePhone}"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>                        
                    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Email}" />
                        <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Phone}"/>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Title}" />
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                    <apex:outputPanel id="testRender">
                        <apex:pageBlockSection />
                        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Show PageBlockSection" collapsible="false" rendered="{IF(CONTAINS(!contact.Choose_Number__c == 'Four'),true, false)}" >
                        </apex:pageBlockSection>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```